# how to add Deep Link and Universal Link Support in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, deep-linking, android-deep-link, flutter-add-to-app

is there any way we can add support for Deep Link and Universal Link ?

i want to add deep link or universal link support into my app so when user click on the link then they redirected to the app instead of the website.

Answer (score 0):

Use the flutter package https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links for this. They all instructions on how to set it up both for android and ios.